# Para que serve o valor "module" na propriedade type do elemento HTML <script>

Tags: javascript, html, html5, módulo-ecmascript

Recentemente vi um código que, ao incluir um arquivo *JavaScript* era setado o atributo `type` com o valor `module` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<script type="module" src="arquivo.js"></script>
```

Gostaria de saber para que serve esse valor, consequentemente, essa pergunta traz outra dentro de si mesmo:

- Compatibilidade do navegador

Answer (score 6):

O `module` é novo recurso no *ECMAScript 6ª edição* (ES6). Quando você seta o atributo `type="module"` a um arquivo `.js`, você o converte em um `módulo`.

Um módulo é um arquivo JS normal, mas com algumas peculiaridades:

- O código de um módulo automaticamente ganha `"use strict";`, mesmo que você não defina isso nele;
- Você pode usar os métodos `import` e `export` nos módulos para intercambiar objetos como `function`, `class`, `var`, `let`, ou `const`.

Tudo o que é declarado dentro de um módulo, por padrão, é local para o módulo. Se você deseja que algo declarado em um módulo seja público, para que outros módulos possam usá-lo, você deve exportar esse recurso (`export`), e para outro módulo usá-lo, deverá importá-lo (`import`).

Quanto à compatibilidade, o MDN mostra a [seguinte tabela](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na mesma página é informado:

> This feature is only just beginning to be implemented in browsers
>   natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as
>   TypeScript and Babel, and bundlers such as Rollup, Webpack and Parcel.

Tradução livre:

> Este recurso está apenas começando a ser implementado de forma nativa
>   nos navegadores neste momento. Está implementado em vários
>   transpiladores, como TypeScript e Babel, e agrupadores como Rollup,
>   Webpack e Parcel.

Answer (score 4):

Os módulos JavaScript permitem que um programa seja dividido em múltiplas sequências de declarações. Cada módulo identifica explicitamente as declarações que ele usa e que precisam ser fornecidas por outros módulos e quais das suas declarações estão disponíveis para uso por outros módulos.

Em navegadores compatíveis com HTML5 o código é tratado como um módulo de JavaScript. O processamento do conteúdo do `script` não é afetado pelo `charset` e *defer* atributos. Para obter informações sobre o uso do módulo veja aqui: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

Documentação do Chrome sobre o assunto: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232

Documentação da Mozilla sobre o assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Demo: https://paulirish.github.io/es-modules-todomvc/

Sobre a compatibilidade do navegador veja como está o Standards: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element (última atualização em 7 de Março de 2018)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module