# Unexpected token no import

Tags: javascript

Está dando o seguinte erro de *syntax* no plugin `typed.js`:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> ```

Nessas linhas:

```
import { initializer } from './initializer.js';
import { htmlParser } from './html-parser.js';
```

Creio que não era pra acontecer isso, por que ele acusa este erro?

Comment: O erro deve estar dentro de um desses .js

Comment: Qual navegador vc tá usando?

Comment: To usando o Chrome, o arquivo JS que está dando erro é esse: https://lucasdecarvalho.com/guiacomercialnf/_cdn/typed.js

Comment: Da uma olhada na linha 353 e 354, está correto?

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando um arquivo JS que funciona como módulo ([veja uma resposta sobre módulos aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281207/8063)).

Para usar o recurso `import` do módulo, é preciso carregar o script com o atributo `type="module"`:

```
<script type="module" src="typed.js"></script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dvd, obrigado! Mas agora está dando um erro diferente:

Comment: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html"

Comment: Sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Vc tah usando em servidor ou no computador?

Comment: Servidor Apache

Comment: Se tiver outro navegador que nao seja o IE, tenta abrir nele para ver se ocorre o erro.